# How to sum the value of each rows and colum of html table

Tags: php, matrix, sum

I make a table like this code:

```
$righe = $_REQUEST['c'];
$colonne = $_REQUEST['c2'];
$somma = 0;
echo"<table width='200' border='1'>";

for($a=1;$a<=$righe;$a++)
{
    echo"<tr bgcolor='#0099FF'>";

    for($b=1;$b<=$colonne;$b++)
    {   
        $somma++;
        $totale = $somma;
        echo"<td><input type='text' name='' size='8' value =" .$totale. " /></td>";
    }

echo"</tr>";
}

echo"</table>";
```

Now i want display the sum of each rows and column of the html table.
For example I chose a matrix of: 5*5 so i have:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   
  6   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15
 16  17  18  19  20
 21  22  23  24  25
```

I want display to the left of each row and in each column the appropriate sum, such as:

`row(1) => 15, row(2) => 40, row(3) => 65` and so on..
`column(1) => 55 , column(2) => 60` and so on..

How to make this?

Comment: I've try with some foreach but, unfortunately don't seems the correct solution for this algorithm

Comment: And you want to display the sum of each row and column to the left?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice, but just the fact that I work out the sum

Comment: You were right, updated it now it works for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $row = $_REQUEST['c'];
    $column = $_REQUEST['c2'];


    echo"<table width='200' border='1'>";

    //Header
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#0099FF'><td><input type='text' name='' size='8' value ='Row Sum:' /></td>";
    foreach(range(1, $column) as $innerValue)
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='' size='8' value =' ' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";


        foreach(range(1, $row + 1) as $value) {

            //Column Sum
            if($value == $row + 1) {
                echo "<tr bgcolor='#0099FF'><td><input type='text' name='' size='8' value ='Column Sum:' /></td>";
                foreach(range(1, $column) as $innerValue)
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='' size='8' value =" . array_sum(range($innerValue, ($innerValue+(($row-1)*$column)), $column)) . " /></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                break;
            }

            echo"<tr bgcolor='#0099FF'>";

            //Row Sum
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='' size='8' value =" . (array_sum(range(1+(($value-1)*$column), $column+(($value-1)*$column)))) . " /></td>";

            //Values
            foreach(range(1, $column) as $innerValue)
                echo"<td><input type='text' name='' size='8' value =" . ($innerValue+(($value-1)*$column)) . " /></td>";

            echo"</tr>";
        }


    echo"</table>";


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$rows = $_REQUEST['c'];
$columns = $_REQUEST['c2'];

$row_sum = array();
$column_sum = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
  echo '<tr>';
  for($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++){
    $tmp = $i*$columns+($j+1);
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='' size='8' value='$tmp'/></td>";
    $row_sum[$i] += $tmp;
    $column_sum[$j] += $tmp; 
  }
  echo "<td>$row_sum[$i]</td></tr>";
}
echo '<tr>';
for($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++){
  echo "<td>$column_sum[$i]</td>";
}
echo '</tr>';
```

You use `$i` and `$j` values that indicate at which column or row are you at in your iteration and sum all the values that belong to the same column or row in `$column_sum` and `$row_sum` respectively.

**EDIT**:
If you need to print the sum on the left (before you iterate trough that row) you will need to precalculate the sum. You can define two functions

```
function sum_row($row, $total_columns){
    $s = $total_columns * $row + 1;
    $e = $s + $total_columns-1;
    return ($e + 1 - $s) * ($e + $s) / 2;
}

function sum_column($column, $total_rows, $total_columns){
    $sum = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $total_rows; $i++){
        $sum += $i*$total_columns+$column+1;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

And then use them where you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do would be like this, take the first value in each row and add itself to the total with +1,+2 and so on

**updated** so it can be any column number

```
$max = 80;
$column = 8;
echo '
    <table border="1">
        <tr>            
            <td>total</td>
        ';
for ($x = 1; $x <= $column; $x++) {
    echo '
            <td>' . $x . '</td>
        ';
}
echo '</tr>';
for ($x = 1; $x <= $max; $x++) {
    if ($x % $column == 1) {
        $total = $x;
        $value = $total;
        for ($y = 1; $y < $column; $y++) {
            $total = $total + $value + $y;
        }
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $total . '</td>
                <td>' . $x . '</td>
            ';
    } elseif ($x % $column == 0) {
        echo '
                <td>' . $x . '</td>
            </tr>
            ';
    } else {
        echo '
                <td>' . $x . '</td>
            ';
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if the number of columns change?

Comment: This calc only row value?